# Why does String.split() return extra elements here?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to split a string using regexp which returns extra element in the array. Please help. following is the program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
    String str1 = "{abc}{def}";
    String delim = "[{}]+";

    String[] tokens = str1.split(delim);

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("token value: "+ tokens[i]);
        }        
    }    
}
```

**output:**

```
token value: 
token value: abc
token value: def
```

Why is first token empty string? How can this be fixed?

Comment: please take a look at the updated title. it's much clearer what you want to know now. Consider the title the "eyecatcher" of your question. If it's just a number of related words, then it's not very eye-catching.

Comment: Just for curiosity: is the input in JSON format? That has "{}" and "[]" notations. In that case you probably better use a JSON parser.

Answer (score 7):

The reason you have the empty initial element is that the target string starts with a delimiter. So just like splitting `",1,2"` on `,` would result in three entries, the first being blank, you get the same result. (You don't get a blank at the *end* because `String#split` explicitly removes them unless you give it a negative second argument.)

If you know the string will start with the delimiter and that it's one character, just remove it:

```
String[] tokens = str1.substring(1).split(delim);
```

*Edit: Or for the general case, [see Bohemian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516101/157247) where he removes the first matching delim regardless of length.*

Otherwise, you can loop:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class SplitTest {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        String str1 = "{abc}{def}";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]+)\\}").matcher(str1);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("token value: " + m.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a breakdown of that pattern string:

- The `\\{` at the beginning matches a literal `{`
- The `(` and the corresponding `)` later create a *capture group*
- Within the capture group, the `[^}]+` means "one or more of any character that isn't a `}`
- The trailing `\\}` match a literal `}`

Then we loop through matches in the string, getting the value of the capture group

Comment: I wonder if the Pattern.compile, or the String.split is more efficient. Maybe it's just easier to omit that leading empty string in case of @Raj.

Comment: @Bohemian: Perhaps the OP doesn't actually need an array, and of course there's a lot of utility is showing how to properly loop. AND I did open saying "you could just strip the first delim." Also, note that it's four lines vs. one, hardly "so many lines." The code block just shows a *complete* test class, is all.

Comment: @CsabaToth: One advantage of `Pattern.compile` is that if you're going to do this more than once, you compile the `Pattern` once, and reuse it. `String#split` compiles each time (barring `Pattern` caching in the implementation, of course).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see: "An invocation of this method of the form `str.split(regex, n)` yields the same result as the expression `Pattern.compile(regex).split(str, n)`".

Comment: I fail to understand why you need to do `[^}]`? Wouldn't a simple pattern like `"\\{(.+?)\\}"` would have worked?

Comment: @Kshitij: That would *also* have worked, yes, because you're making the quantifier non-greedy. Six of one, half-dozen of the other...

Comment: A) i detest dxcessive lines. B) I agree about the efficiency of caching pattern, but you would have to use it a lot (eg tight loop processing a large file) to warrant using 4 times as many lines - it's optimising early. Another solution would to use Arrays.copyOfRange() to strip off the leading element.

Comment: @Bohemian: Again: If the OP doesn't actually need an **array** (they just want to loop), there isn't even one extra line. It's either compile (1 line) and loop on the matches (2-3 depending on style), or split (1 line) and loop through the array (2-3 depending on style). Same count either way.

Comment: Not so re line count being the same. you can't in-line, but my code will - see edit to my answer. Just for you :)

Comment: @Bohemian: Oh, don't be daft. You could put your entire source file on one line if you liked. Doesn't mean you should.

Comment: It's still only two lines max. And it's actually only one line because there's only one semicolon. It isn't "daft" or some extreme formatting (unless your whole source only had one semicolon). There's an option in Eclipse to put if+line on one line, eg `if (something) then return;`, so it's even not even fringe. I'd be claiming it if it was a puzzle. Admit when you're beat :D

Comment: @Bohemian: Here's a clue: It's not a competition. We're just trying to help the OP solve their problem. Both solutions have merit, as I've highlighted in my answer and in comments on your answer. Badgering someone about the line count of their solution is not, frankly, useful or a worthwhile use of your time or theirs.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that it is splitting before the first char. To fix, simply strip off the leading delimiters before splitting:

```
String[] tokens = str1.replaceAll("^" + delim, "").split(delim);
```

---

If you just need to loop over the parts (and not keep the array, you can make the whole working part of your method into just two lines:

```
for (String token : str1.replaceAll("^" + delim, "").split(delim))
    System.out.println("token value: " + token);
```

Or just one line (there's only one semicolon!) if you don't mind wide lines:

```
for (String token : str1.replaceAll("^" + delim, "").split(delim)) System.out.println("token value: " + token);
```

Comment: "^" matches the start of the string, so using that you can phrase such regex which won't match the beginning delimiters. I'm too busy to come up with it now.

Comment: @CsabaToth See edited answer - I changed it minutes ago (seconds after I posted the first version, which I immediately realised wouldn't work because it would leave the first token containing the leading brace

Comment: @T.J.Crowder no it won't! The delim is a character class! It will become `"^[{}]+"`

Comment: @Bohemian: Sorry, I was thinking of the delim you need if you're **not** using `split`! (And I was off to see why `split` didn't mind them...) I quite like this solution.

Comment: Hi Bohemian, this works :) thanks. But not sure about the concept. What if there is no delimiter in the beginning? Or it will always be the case? I do not think so... Is there a way that i can validate the string with respect to regexp?

Comment: If i remove + in the end of regex then it gives empty string after every token! why?

Comment: @Raj You can validate it before stripping off. But then it maybe just easier to omit a leading empty string from the split results. It depends on your use-case if it matters if there was any lading delimiter or not.

Comment: @Raj: *"What if there is no delimiter in the beginning?"* That's not a problem, the `replaceAll` will just become a no-op and pass the string unchanged to `split`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about the language / formatting of your input, then you can do this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
    String str1 = "{abc}{def}";

    String[] tokens = str1.split("}");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String realToken = tokens[i].substring(1); // This strips off the leading "{"
        System.out.println("token value: " + realToken);
    }
}
```

Why the leading empty string token in your original example? This is because the string starts with a delimiter. Think about it: if it wouldn't return an empty string as the first element in your case, how would you distinguish between those cases when a string starts with a delimiter and when it does not?